# How would I go about syncing text through multiple webpages on the same website?

Tags: web, html

I would like to have a text box at the top of my website on every page that has the same text, but I don't want to edit the code individually for every webpage. How would I sync the text to all the webpages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include Common files using jQuery...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
Main Content
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#header").load("header.html");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```